# Query All Profile Pics that are Friends in

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to return & display all of the user profile images from the DB, but only those whom are friends of the person in that particular profile.  The DB is structure like this:

[usersDBstructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVLUD.jpg)

The friend_array is separated by ,
I have the following for access and display:

```
<?php
global $con;

$username = $_GET['profile_username'];
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE profile_pic = '$username'");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $friends = $row['profile_pic']; 
?>
     <div><img src="<?php echo $friends; ?>"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm certain it's the query, however any help on how to better make this query would be awesome.

Thankyou.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with it or are you asking for improvements? If it's the letter it may be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi Matt, there was no output error but the result wasn't displaying, so I assumed it was the query.  I tried Jason's code below and it worked perfectly.

Comment: fair play, glad you found your solution :) I was just asking because I was unsure of the exact question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need something like this:

`$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username'");`

You are looking for people who are friends of `$username`, so you need to be checking against friend_array. I used LIKE because it gives us easier searching against a comma-separated field (a straight `=` won't work for partial matches). We have to check 3 separate possible ways of matching because a username may be the first username, may be in the middle of the list, or may be the last, and each of the three have a different format.

Comment: Thankyou so much Jason.  Great heads up on the commas.  I plugged in the query and poof the pictures displayed...finally.  I must have tried at least 10 variations on that query!

Comment: @EP19 In that case, could you upvote and mark my answer as the correct answer? Thanks!